# TextView doesn't show in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-relativelayout

I have a `TextView` which work normally but if I try to show `TextView` in `RelativeLayout` it doesn't show.("//this section begin and end")

My `XML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFF"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutContent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <com.gc.materialdesign.views.LayoutRipple
                android:id="@+id/itemSimple"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:clickable="true">

                <!--this section - begin-->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="#e91e63"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                        android:text="sample text"
                        android:textColor="#727272"
                        android:textSize="17dp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
                <!--this section - end-->

            </com.gc.materialdesign.views.LayoutRipple>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.gc.materialdesign.views.ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

if i want this code work, i must define more space for `width` and `height` of `RelativeLayout`, but i don't want. i want my `RelativeLayout` as the same `width` and `height` as i specify.

thanks...

Comment: For text view try making width and height as `match_parent`. See what happens

Comment: In the Relativelayout just add `android:layout_below="@id/itemSimpleJelly"`

Comment: @Ranjith It seems that the `RelativeLayout` is inside the custom view having id as `itemSimpleJelly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RelativeLayout` has a `height` of `25dp` and a `padding` of `20dp`. Means there are only `5dp` left for the text - not enough to display characters. You need to decrease the `padding` or increase the `height`.

```
<!--this section - begin-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"    <--------------------------------
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#e91e63"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">   <--------------------------------

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:text="sample text"
        android:textColor="#727272"
        android:textSize="17dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<!--this section - end-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use those value of height and width for your `RelativeLayout` and there's a simply explanation: you are using `25dp` for `height` of the `RelativeLayout` and `20dp` for `padding-bottom`. `5dp` aren't enough for a `TextView` with text-size of `17dp`. Now the decision is yours. You can delete the padding-bottom from that `RelativeLayout` or increase his `height` or decrease the `textSize`. I think that delete the padding is the best solution:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#e91e63">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:text="sample text"
        android:textColor="#727272"
        android:textSize="17dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```